# Why the alias is put in front of the 'AS' keyword in a 'WITH subquery' in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Normally, I have come to be used to having the alias at the right of the 'AS' keyword in SQL statements. However, this is not the case in a 'WITH' subquery (at least in Postgres). For instance you would write:

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM ....).
```

Why is this the case? Do we have other similar cases in postgres? Is this SQL-standard?

Comment: This the way the syntax for a common table expressions is defined in the SQL standard. The syntax for a column or table alias is simply different to the syntax of a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps for the same reason that the "alias" is put in front of the `as` when naming a view.

The ultimate answer is that the SQL standard defines common table expressions with this syntax.  I don't think anyone ever accused SQL of being overly consistent, but I actually think your question is reasonable.  This seems like a syntax gotcha that could confuse people learning SQL.

Comment: I do think it's inconsistent. When a new "object" is created the name is always in front of the keyword `as`, e.g.: `create table x as select ...` or the one you mentioned: `create view v as select ..`. The name of the CTE isn't an "alias" anyway in my opinion. An "alias" gives a new name to something existing. The name defined for the CTE gives a single name to something _new_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Interesting perspective.  I don't see a CTE as anything new, because even if materialized, it only exists for the duration of the statement -- in that sense, it is quite similar to an alias on a subquery, but with slightly different scoping rules.  In any case, sometimes newbie questions are interesting because they highlight something that more seasoned people just wouldn't think about.